# javascript sum with parseFloat giving wronge value

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var c = parseFloat("10.81") +parseFloat("10.00");
alert(c);
}
```

//output is 20.810000000000002 why?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in most languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toFixed` to get the precision to two digit floating number. In that case you will get the desired result:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var c = parseFloat("10.81") +parseFloat("10.00");
  alert(c.toFixed(2));
}
//output is 20.810000000000002 why?

myFunction();
```